# How to do diagram block with open source software?

Tags: qgis, dem, 3d, topography, geology

I would like to do a block diagram (topographic and geological representation). Is it possible to do this with QGIS (or other open source software), in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

This strongly depends of the data structures you have. I think some voxel reperesentation is required for the kind of diagrams you mention. Perhaps GRASS GIS is a worth a consideration:

https://grass.osgeo.org/screenshots/3D/